# How can i set label text from listbox item value? c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, label

I want to make label text like value from listbox item. For example - how can i show listbox item "BrojGlasova" (that is int) like label text?

I tried to make label3.Text = listBox1.DisplayMember but than in my listbox there are no names, only numbers, but i want names to stay in listbox and only on click on selected item to show in label their number.

Sorry for my english! :D

```
    private void PodaciOJutjuberima_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void PostaviPodatke()
    {
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "NazivKanala";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "BrojGlasova";

        listBox1.Items.Add(new Jutjuber { NazivKanala = "Yasserstain", BrojPretplatnika = 300000, BrojGlasova = 15000 });
        listBox1.Items.Add(new Jutjuber { NazivKanala = "SrpskiTutorijali", BrojPretplatnika = 250000, BrojGlasova = 12000 });
        listBox1.Items.Add(new Jutjuber { NazivKanala = "KovalskA", BrojPretplatnika = 150000, BrojGlasova = 10000 });
        listBox1.Items.Add(new Jutjuber { NazivKanala = "PCAXE", BrojPretplatnika = 60000, BrojGlasova = 8000 });
        listBox1.Items.Add(new Jutjuber { NazivKanala = "Kika", BrojPretplatnika = 75000, BrojGlasova = 9000 });
        listBox1.Items.Add(new Jutjuber { NazivKanala = "SupremeNexus", BrojPretplatnika = 500000, BrojGlasova = 8500 });
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int dodaj = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
        for (int i = dodaj; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (listBox1.GetSelected(i))
            {
                listBox1.DisplayMember = "BrojGlasova";
                label3.Text = listBox1.DisplayMember;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: try listBox1.SelectecItem.Value or (listBox1.SelectecItem as Jutjuber).BrojGlasova

Comment: Thanks, you helped me.

label3.Text = Convert.ToString((listBox1.SelectedItem as Jutjuber).BrojGlasova);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
private void PodaciOJutjuberima_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void PostaviPodatke()
    {
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "NazivKanala";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "BrojGlasova";

        listBox1.Items.Add(new Jutjuber { NazivKanala = "Yasserstain", BrojPretplatnika = 300000, BrojGlasova = 15000 });
        listBox1.Items.Add(new Jutjuber { NazivKanala = "SrpskiTutorijali", BrojPretplatnika = 250000, BrojGlasova = 12000 });
        listBox1.Items.Add(new Jutjuber { NazivKanala = "KovalskA", BrojPretplatnika = 150000, BrojGlasova = 10000 });
        listBox1.Items.Add(new Jutjuber { NazivKanala = "PCAXE", BrojPretplatnika = 60000, BrojGlasova = 8000 });
        listBox1.Items.Add(new Jutjuber { NazivKanala = "Kika", BrojPretplatnika = 75000, BrojGlasova = 9000 });
        listBox1.Items.Add(new Jutjuber { NazivKanala = "SupremeNexus", BrojPretplatnika = 500000, BrojGlasova = 8500 });
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label3.Text = (listBox1.SelectedItem as Jutjuber).BrojGlasova.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In a listbox you can load objects, In DisplayMember and ValueMember what property of the object you want to assign in your listbox, finally you can recover the selected item, and query the property you need to show an assign it to you textbox